# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0)

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I am currently on magento 1.9.1 and it worked fine. I wanted to uppgrade Zend Framework from 1.12.7 to 1.12.13.

After uppdating i got this error message when logging in to backend.

--

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(ma' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `lifetime`, `AVG((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `average` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.status NOT IN('canceled')) AND (main_table.state NOT IN('new', 'pending_payment'))

Trace:
#0 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#4 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#5 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#6 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#7 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `SUM((IF...', Array)
#8 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php(65): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Sales->_prepareLayout()
#11 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#13 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#14 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#15 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#16 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#17 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#20 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#21 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#22 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#23 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#24 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#25 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 /home/4/t/tedragen/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}
```

Tried deleting catch and sessions. But dont know what to do else. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

edit: Try completely deleting the old Zend Framework in lib and then copy the new one in. Make sure there are no old files left behind.

edit 2: My issue was that I was using Aoe_Classpathcache and I didn't know APC was on (thought I had cleared the cache by deleting the var/cache/classpathcache.php file, but it was still there in APC)

old answer:
I can consistently reproduce this issue in Magento 1.9.2, probably because 
1.9.2 upgraded to Zend Framework version 1.12.10 
(http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.html).

This happens even on a completely stock Magento version (installation done with an existing app/etc/local.xml, not by following the wizard). What worked for me was to downgrade to 1.9.1.

Why did you upgrade Zend Framework anyway? It's a bad idea since Magento use their own fork of ZF afaik.